# Jquery document on change: can I use variable as selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am very new to javascript and jQuery.  In my view, I have a List of QuoteDetails, as follows:

```
<div class="col-md-10" id="QuoteDetails">
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.QuoteDetail.Count; i++)
    {
        <div id="row">
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.QuoteDetail[i].QuoteId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.QuoteDetail[i].QuoteDetailId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.QuoteDetail[i].ProductId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "PId", @class = "form-control", style = "width: 75px" } })
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.QuoteDetail[i].ProductName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "Product", @class = "form-control", style = "width: 300px" } })
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.QuoteDetail[i].Amount, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", style = "width: 95px" } })
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.QuoteDetail[i].ListPrice, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "Lprice", @class = "form-control", style = "width: 95px" } })
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.QuoteDetail[i].Discount, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", style = "width: 100px" } })
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.QuoteDetail[i].Price, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "Pr", @class = "form-control", style = "width: 100px" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.QuoteDetail, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    }
```

When either the Amount or Discount is changed by the user, I want to recalculate the Price.  I am trying to solve it with the following javascript/jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var quoteDetails = $('[name*="QuoteDetailId"]');
        var amounts = $('[id*="Amount"]')
        var discounts = $('[id*="Discount"]')
        var prices = $('[id*="Price"]')
        var listPrices = $('[id*="LPrice"]')
          for (var i = 0; i < quoteDetails.length; i++) {
            $(document).on("change", discounts[i], amounts[i], function calculate() {  
                var finalPrice = $(amounts[i]).val() * ($(listPrices[i]).val() * ((100 - $(discount[i]).val()) / 100)) 
                $(prices[i]).val(finalPrice);
            });
        };
    });
</script>
```

Is there a way to use variables with indices as jQuery selectors in the document.on change?  Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Give you elements class names and use relative selectors

Comment: Can you give me an example of what you have in mind?

Comment: If you intend to use `.on` ***indirectly*** (like events delegating), then why not use it on the closest parent (which is the div `#row`). Then you don't need to specify the `selector`. All the `change` events originating from the descendants inside should propagate (but note that <= IE9 won't work this way). So I think the safest way is attaching the handler ***directly*** on the elements that you loop through, like this: `$([discounts[i], amounts[i]]).on("change",  function calculate() { ... })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your elements class names, e.g

```
@Html.EditorFor(m=> m.QuoteDetail[i].Amount, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control amount"} })
```

and change the container to `<div class="row">`

(ditto for `discount`, `listprice` and `price`)

Then your script becomes

```
$('.amount, .discount').change(function() {
    // Get container
    var row = $(this).closest('.row');
    // Get values
    var amount = Number(row.find('.amount').val());
    var listprice = Number(row.find('.listprice').val());
    var discount = Number(row.find('.discount').val()); 
    // Validate
    if (isNaN(amount) || isNaN(listprice) || isNaN(discount))
    {
        return; // may want to display an error message?
    }
    // Calculate
    var finalPrice = amount * listprice * ((100 - discount) / 100)
    // Update
    row.find('.price').val(finalPrice);
})
```

A few things to note:

- Duplicate `id` attributes are invalid html - remove all your `new {
  @id = ".."` code.
- Because of your class names, you can now style the widths - e.g.
  `.price { width: 95px; }`
- Convert the values to a `Number` and check
  that the value is valid using `isNaN` before doing the calculation
- Since `Price` is a calculated field, it should not be editable in the
  view (or have a `setter` in the model. Use a `<div>` or similar
  element to display it (and then use
  `row.find('.price').text(finalPrice);` to set it

Note also that `.on()` is not necessary unless your dynamically adding those elements after the view has been first generated.

Comment: Thanks for your comments.  Will make the changes.  Everything looks great, but the final update isn't taking place.  Any idea why?

Comment: Also (not related but) your not handling the `.change()` event of the `.listprice'` element - if that should not be edited, then at least make it `new { @readonly = "readonly" `. And you have a `ValidationMessageFor(m => m.QuoteDetail)` which does not make a lot of sense, since `QuoteDetail` is a collection (unless you adding a `ModelStateError` in the POST method and returning the view. Yet none of you inputs have `ValidationMessageFor()` which they should

Comment: I get no errors in the browser console except "main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience."  Using alerts, the values of amount, discount and listprice are all NaN.  Why would this be?

Comment: Are they valid numbers (and with `.` as decimal separator)?

Comment: Also since you have stated your new to javascript, I strongly recommend you learn how to use you browser tools to debug scripts (for Chrome, refer [docs](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/)). Also I create a fiddle for you shortly to show how it works.

Comment: I just notices that you have `<div id="row">` - that needs to be `<div class="row">`

Comment: Changing the div to class=row made it work!  Thank you very much!

Comment: Oops, that should have been `isNan(..)` not `!is(Nan(..)` (you want to exit if any of those values are not a number

Comment: Would you post a link to the fiddle?

Comment: Refer [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qod1tq2j/). Note a bit of extra validation to check if the values are `null`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138380/discussion-between-dwight-mendoza-and-stephen-muecke).